# How can I find files that are not in use by any process and remove them?

Tags: wine, lsof

I found that `~/.wine/drive_c/users/t/Temp/` has 1.4G bytes of files `*.tmp`. Some of them are in use by some processes (and I can tell for each file by `lsof`), and the other are not  in use by any processs.

Do the files under the directory   temporarily store information used by the Wine client processes?

Are the files safe to remove?

If I can only remove those that are not in used by any wine client processes, how shall I write a command  that can automatically find such files and remove them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Removing files isn't under Wine's control, in unix you can delete a directory entry for an open file.  The file remains until it's closed by the process(es) using it.

Doing what you're after, choosing the not-currently-open files so you can have your way with them, is a race between you looking and processes opening and closing (and possibly creating and deleting) them. Avoiding that race is the province of mainframe job entry subsystems and job control language.  But if "usually quite recent" is close enough to current for you, list all the files, list all the open files, anything not listed twice existed when you looked but wasn't open when you looked at almost the same time (or was open when you looked but didn't exist when you looked at almost the same time, which is why I do the lsof first here).

On GNU/anything,

```
sort -r <<EOD | uniq -u | while read; do test -f "$REPLY" && echo rm "${REPLY@Q}"; done
$( cd targetdir
   lsof -Fn +D $PWD | sed -n /^n/s/.//p
   find $PWD -printf %p\\n
)
EOD
```

will spit the list of commands to remove files that look safe to remove.

But usually you just wipe your temp dir at startup with some protection for the most recent files,

```
find $TMPDIR -ctime +6 -delete
```

for instance, deletes everything made at least a week ago.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
echo rm -f ~/.wine/drive_c/users/t/Temp/*(D.^e['fuser -s $REPLY'])
```

(remove the `echo` when happy)

That removes the regular files (`.`) (including hidden ones (`D`)) for which `fuser` does not (`^`) find any *user* process.

Replace `*` with `**/*` if you want to do it recursively or you could also do it with `find`:

```
find ~/.wine/drive_c/users/t/Temp -type f ! -exec fuser -s {} \; \
   -exec echo rm -f {} +
```

(replace `-exec rm -f {} +` with `-delete` if your `find` implementation supports it).